# Nested Table Issue in VisualForce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I have a table inside of a pageBlockSection on a force.com apex template. This works fine until I try to use an outputText tag inside of one of my cells.  When I use this tag, extra cells and rows are added to the markup.  However, if I do NOT nest my table inside of a pageBlockSection tag, no such cells are added.

Am I using outputText incorrectly, or is there a bug on force.com?

Here is the minimal markup that will reproduce this issue:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="My Page Block">    
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Section">   
    <table>
      <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th></tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <apex:outputText value="{0}">
            <apex:param value="one" />
          </apex:outputText>
        </td>
        <td>
          <apex:outputText value="{0}">
            <apex:param value="two" />
          </apex:outputText>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>    
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Here is the output rendered by force.com:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th></tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="dataCol  first ">one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="dataCol "></td>
      <td></td>
      <td colspan="2" class="dataCol ">two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" class="dataCol  last "></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

Whether it's actually a bug I cannot say, but I believe it's caused by the `<apex:pageBlockSection>` as these automatically add nested content into a table, which is then clashing with your own table.

I would suggest either removing the `<apex:pageBlockSection>` and putting your table directly into the `<apex:pageBlock>`, or removing your own table and leveraging the `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` element instead:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="My Page Block">    
  <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Section">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      1
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      2
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputText value="{0}">
        <apex:param value="one" />
      </apex:outputText>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
      <apex:outputText value="{0}">
        <apex:param value="two" />
      </apex:outputText>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around this issue by placing the table within an outputPanel tag.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
   <apex:outputPanel>
      <table>
      </table>
   </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```